# How can I replace the following 2 commands to use BSON file?

Tags: mongodb

I use the following command to backup my local db

```
mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 8001 -d meteor -c products --archive --gzip > dump.gz
```

Then I use the following command to restore on my server

```
cat dump.gz | ssh root@66.205.148.23 "cat | docker exec -i mongodb mongorestore --archive --gzip"
```

I want to do the same but with only one collection. Adding the -c parameter to the above commands does not work when trying to restore. I get a message that states that the -c param can only be used with BSON files.

How can I do the above for only one collection using the -c parameter?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [--out](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-out) option for `mongodump` instead of `--archieve` to write `BSON` files

> Specifies the directory where mongodump will write BSON files for the dumped databases. By default, mongodump saves output files in a directory named dump in the current working directory.
>
> To send the database dump to standard output, specify “-” instead of a path. Write to standard output if you want process the output before saving it, such as to use gzip to compress the dump. When writing standard output, mongodump does not write the metadata that writes in a .metadata.json file when writing to files directly.
>
> You cannot use the --archive option with the --out option.

---

This will create folder `dump` with `BSON` files

> mongodump -h 127.0.0.1 --port 8001 -d meteor --gzip --out dump

To restore:

> mongorestore -h 127.0.0.1 --port 8001 -d meteor --gzip -c collname foo dump/meteor/collname.bson.gz

Comment: Can I still use --gzip ? Could you please type the commands and I will accept your answer?

Comment: Updated my answer. Sure, you can use --gzip. Now, `mongodump` will create for each collection separate `.gz` file. Try it

Comment: One more thing please, the mongodump command works fine. But how can I make the second command work on my server with a different ip? Please add the ssh stuff to the second command.

Comment: You can add new `volume` for mongodb container, move `dump` folder there and enter inside docker container (`docker exec -it mongodb /bin/bash`) and restore